# Como capturar el detalle de error de una ETL SSIS

Tags: ssis

necesito capturar el detalle de error en una ETL (SSIS)
para luego enviar el error como alerta en mail
[image: El detalle del error destacado en amarillo]
el detalle del error está destacado en amarillo
mi idea principal es capturar ese detalle para enviarlo como mensaje.
Como?...
asignando parámetros a una tarea sql pero no logro encontrar como capturar dicho detalle
de ante mano muchas gracias.

PD. he buscado en foros...google y nada se acerca a lo que necesito, sin mencionar que probé las variables disponibles (SYSTEM::)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solucion gracias al link que me respondió el compa Roger
1. click en la pestaña Controlador de eventos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2.Click en el link para crear un controlador de evento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3.Arrastro al "Controlador de eventos" cualquier task, en las expresiones de sistema aparecen las variables de error para usar expresiones en donde quiera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente la cosa es así. Digamos que tengo una tarea sql y quiero recibir un correo electrónico sobre "error de tarea" con la descripción del error.

```
 1. Arrastramos la tarea de correo electrónico para que en caso de error en la tarea sql entre en esta nueva tarea.
 2. En la tarea en correo electrónico introducimos la configuración: conexión SMTP, email, asunto, etc.
 3. Creamos variables de usuario para el mensaje de error.
 4. Establecemos el controlador de eventos para la tarea fallida o en caso de error y creamos la tarea de secuencia de comandos en el nivel de paquete.
 5. En la tarea de script ... necesitamos asignar las variables del sistema y las variables de usuario.
 6. Nos aseguramos de las propiedades: deshabilitar el controlador de eventos deben estar a falso, solo leerá las variables del sistema.
```

En [este enlace](https://www.fourmoo.com/2014/08/06/ssis-error-handling-and-error-emailing-for-packages/) tienes una descripción detallada, aunque en inglés.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió el link. responderé los pasos que hice para hacerlo posible.